# Declare A Column Name As A Variable

Tags: sql, sybase

I am running into an issue with the query below.

```
DECLARE @CC VARCHAR(100)
SET @CC = 'MKT_COV_CAR_LFR'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(16384)
SET @SQL =      
'INSERT INTO PP_Industry
SELECT
    R.Year,
    ''01'' AS Carline,
    Sales_Locality,
    '+@CC+' AS Reg, 
    National_Reg,
    CAST('+@CC+' AS FLOAT) / CAST(National_Reg AS FLOAT) AS Reg_Share
FROM
    PP_Registrations AS R
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                Year,
                SUM('+@CC+') AS National_Reg
            FROM
                PP_Registrations
            GROUP BY
                Year
        ) AS SQ ON R.Year = SQ.Year'

EXEC @SQL
```

I receive the following error when I run it. Please help!

> Error (2812) Stored procedure 'INSERT INTO PP_Industry
>       SELECT
>           R.Year,
>           '01' AS Carline,
>           Sales_Locality,
>           MKT_COV_CAR_LFR AS Reg, 
>           Nationa' not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).

Answer (score 0):

If you run an custom SQL statement you should execute it like that:

```
exec (@SQL)
```